# Jquery attr doesnt work on Yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I'm trying to change the element value using Jquery but it's not working...

This is my widget where I have my element 'tag' which i want to change it to textField on edit...

```
$this->widget('EditableGrid', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider->searchbyID($invoice_id),
    'template' => '{items}{buttonCreateRow}{pager} ',
    'id' => 'InvoiceLine-grid',
    'rowTemplate' => $row_template,
    'columns' => array(   
            array(
            'class' => 'EditableGridColumn',
            'header' => '',
            'name' => 'InvoiceLine_{gridNum}_{rowNum}_edit',
            'imageurl'=> Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/update.png',
            'tag' => 'button',
            'tagHtmlOptions' => array(
            'onclick'=>'editline(this)',
                )
            ),
            array(
            'class' => 'EditableGridColumn',
            'header' => 'StentysRef',
            'name' => '[{gridNum}][{rowNum}]stentysproductref',
            'tag' => 'laabel',          
            'tagHtmlOptions' => array(
                'style'=>'background-color:#FFF;border-color:#FFF',
            'onkeyup'=>'stentysref(this)',
                'readonly'=>true
                )
            ),
```

My Jquery is,

(as you can see the removeAttr works but attr doesn't)

```
       function editline(obj){
            $("#InvoiceLine_1_"+row+"_stentysproductref").attr("tag","textField");
            $("#InvoiceLine_1_"+row+"_stentysproductref").removeAttr("readonly");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop()` and `removeProp()` which is added in jQuery 1.6, as the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior.

```
function editline(obj){
    $("#InvoiceLine_1_"+row+"_stentysproductref").prop("tag","textField");
    $("#InvoiceLine_1_"+row+"_stentysproductref").removeProp("readonly");
}
```

[API Doc for .prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: are you getting any console error on browser? Please share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement so that I can help you better.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I just want a textfield when i click edit...Any sol?

Comment: also what is `row` for? and you are passing `obj` in `function editline(obj){` but not using it, then why to pass it?

Comment: function editline(obj){
 var status = <?php echo $status;?>; 
 if(status ==  "1")
 {
 var id = obj.id; 
 var trun =  id.substring(14); 
 var row= trun.substr(0, trun.indexOf('_')); 
$("#InvoiceLine_1_"+row+"_stentysproductref").attr("tag","textField");}

Comment: please share your html code and share jsfiddle, which helps me to help you better.

Comment: I have never used Jsfiddle for this.. But somehow I managed to put the whole code in here http://jsfiddle.net/713r7ycw/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EditableGrid widget without pointing AR model, then the row id looks like

```
$('#_1_'+row+'stentysproductref').
```

I'll take it into consideration for the future updates. Thank you.